# Returning results from async function with infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, websocket, async-await

I have an async function that subscribes to a websocket stream. What is the best way to pass received data to other parts of the program from this function?

Below is a short example code. It will subscribe to BTCUSD and BTCETH pairs order book channels via a websocket on Bitfinex exchange and print data to stdout. I need data that is being assigned to `message` to be retrievable from other parts of the program.

```py
import json
import asyncio
import websockets

async def subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request):
    async with websockets.connect(ws_host) as ws:
        request = json.dumps(subscribe_request)
        await ws.send(request)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await ws.recv()
                print(message)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print("Connection was closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws_host = 'wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2'
    subscribe_request_btc = dict( 
                            event='subscribe',
                            channel='book',
                            symbol='tBTCUSD',
                            prec='P0',
                            freq='F1',
                            len='25' 
                            )
    subscribe_request_eth = dict( 
                            event='subscribe',
                            channel='book',
                            symbol='tETHUSD',
                            prec='P0',
                            freq='F1',
                            len='25' 
                            )

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request_btc), subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request_eth)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Lots of options. You can take a callback that you call on every message, or allow clients to register any number of callbacks, or wrap that up in a `Protocol` class, or rewrite your function as an async generator, or… There is no "the best way" for all possibly applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with so far. Create queues for each websocket channel, start a daemon thread that listens to websocket channels and write messages to appropriate queues. The main thread continuously checks if queues have new values in them and dequeues them.

```
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import queue
import threading

async def subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request, q):
    async with websockets.connect(ws_host) as ws:
        request = json.dumps(subscribe_request)
        await ws.send(request)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await ws.recv()
                q.put(message)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print("Connection was closed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws_host = 'wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2'
    subscribe_request_btc = dict( 
                            event='subscribe',
                            channel='book',
                            symbol='tBTCUSD',
                            prec='P0',
                            freq='F1',
                            len='25' 
                            )
    subscribe_request_eth = dict( 
                            event='subscribe',
                            channel='book',
                            symbol='tETHUSD',
                            prec='P0',
                            freq='F1',
                            len='25' 
                            )
    q_btc = queue.Queue()
    q_eth = queue.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request_btc, q_btc), subscribe(ws_host, subscribe_request_eth, q_eth)]
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_until_complete, args=(asyncio.wait(tasks),), daemon=True)
    t1.start()
    while True:
        try:
            message_btc = q_btc.get(block=False)
            print('BTC channel: ', message_btc)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        try:
            message_eth = q_eth.get(block=False)
            print('ETH channel', message_eth)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
    loop.close()
```

Feel free to add answers showing more efficient ways of doing this.